# Overwritten existing fields of an arraylist in android activity.Unable to append new data at the end of existing data in the arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity, overwrite

I have searched for the question a lot but i am not getting a specific answer to my case.

1. I am taking input from the user in the fields name,age,sport.
2. On click of an ADD button,these values should be stored in an arraylist.
3. But if i click on the add button again, i try to append the new  values of inputs below previous inputs of the arraylist.But,the earlier values are overwritten by the new values.

'

```
public class Addpeople extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    public String name ;
    public String   age;
    public String sport;
    EditText etName;
    EditText etAge;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button Add;
    Button Done;
    ArrayList<String[]> arryList=new ArrayList<String[]>();  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addpeople);    
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        etName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etAge= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        Done=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bExit);

        Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name = etName.getText().toString();
                age =  etAge.getText().toString();
                sport =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


                arryList.add(name);
                            arryList.add(age);
                            arryList.add(sport);


            }
        });
        `
```

Comment: Does that mean that all the previous values disappear? If that's so, are you sure that `onCreate()` isn't called between those clicks?

Comment: I'm not sure if 'onClick' method is called or not but on debugging i found that the values are overwritten in the arraylist.

Comment: well try adding log output in `onCreate()` before the line `new ArrayList<String[]>();` it seems to me that this might be the root of the problem. If you create a new arraylist then no wonder all the values are gone..

Comment: Defining the arraylist outside the `onCreate()` method helped in solving  the overwriting problem.Now i am able to pass all the values.Also instead of passing via string array,I have decided to pass the strings directly to the arraylist.thanks.